# Sum the area of buildings inside a block (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, polygon, field-calculator

My problem is to get the sum of the area of all buildings inside a block.

There are a layer with the buildings (they contain an `block_id` to which block they belong and the area) and a layer with all blocks (they have a `block_id`). I want to sum the areas of all buildings with the same `block_id` and store this sum in a new column in the block-layer to the block with this `block_id`.
I add an picture to clarify my question and structure of data. There are two blocks. The left on has the `block_id = '078060'` and the right one `block_id = '078070'`. Now all my buildings in the left polygon have an attritbute also called `block_id` with the value `'078060'`. I want then to sum up all the areas of the buildings in the block and store this value to my block layer.

I thought about calculation this with the field calculator in QGIS. But I don't know how.

The question "[Summing up the area on a polygon by a certain attribute result](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239623/summing-up-the-area-on-a-polygon-by-a-certain-attribute-result)" is just a first step to solve my problem, because the calculated sum for the categories (`block_id`) should be added to a new column in the blocks_layer. I was looking for a possibility to automatically calculate the sum and store it to a new column.

[image]

Comment: look at this https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/239623/49538

Comment: @beajifu To clarify, you have 2 shapefiles (polygons), one of the physical buildings and another intangible layer which encompasses some of these buildings. Each shapefile has a block id so you might have 5 buildings in block 1 and 6 buildings in block 2?

Comment: The attribute table of first layer 'buildings' looks like (id | street | area | block_id | geom) and the 'blocks'-layer looks like (block_id | geom ) . The block_id of the buildings layer is connected to a block with this block_id.
I could have a block with block_id = 123 and two buildings with ( 1 | street a | 100m² | 123) and (2 | street b | 200 m² | 123) .
Now I want to sum the areas of these two buildings (100m²+200m²=300m²) and store this sum to the block with the id 123.

I hope I could clarify what I want to do.

Comment: maybe screenshots would help ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Statistics by categories** tool in the Processing Toolbox in conjunction with joins.

I have created a test dataset with some polygons with `block_id` and `area` field (categorized visualization based on block_id) as well as blocks with an `id`:

[image]

Attribute table looks like this:

[image]

Select **Statistics by categories** tool in the Processing Toolbox:

[image]

Select the field you would like to calculate your statistics on (in your case `area`) and the field containing the category (here the `block_id`)

[image]

What you get is a table with a broad variety of statistical parameters (called *"Statistic by category"*):

[image]

You can now join this table to your block based on the `block_id`. Right click your blocks and under properties selct **Joins**. Click the [image] and fill out the form as shown below:

[image]

If you open your blocks attribute table, you will notice a field called `sum_sum` containing the values just calculated above:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This works pretty well. QGIS is so powerful but sometimes it's hard to find a way to solve a problem.